# changing contact add buttons color in swift

Tags: ios, button

Does anybody know how to give a custom text color to the circled + sign in ContactAdd button type? Before I was thinking the circled + is the actual title of the button but I was wrong.

```
var addButton=UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.ContactAdd) as UIButton
println("this is the current title \(addButton.currentTitle)") \\gives nil
```

Comment: I had a nice long answer typed in but p4sh4 nailed it before I did.  In the meantime, a .ContactAdd button is just a "+" character with no space for a title or titleString, which is why you are seeing nil.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [tint color](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/tintColor) property. Something like this:

```
addButton.tintColor = UIColor.blueColor()
```